# A short bit of programming done for math exam?

Tags: java, math, permutation, combinatorics

I'm taking an exam tomorrow, and on that exam there is a bit about probability. Now on many of those tasks one is to find all the outcomes. That can sometimes be tricky to get right. Let's say you have two players playing rock-paper-scissors. One player is John, the other is Reese. The two play three games in a row. All the possible outcomes of this set with three rounds can be represented as JTR. That would be John wins first round, then there is a tie and then Reese wins a round. I know that there is 3*3*3=27 different outcomes. I am allowed to use my computer on the exam, and a short snippet of code that would given any letters, in this case at least write out all the 27 combinations would be really nice! I only ask in case there is some known algorithm that does this, I'll be hacking away at it myself as of this moment. Any suggestions will be really much appreciated!

Comment: I think writing a program in advance might bias your perspective on the problem that you get. On these types of exams sometimes it is better to come to it with a clear open mind, open to all possibilities. Once you write a program, you have a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: I submitted an edit correcting your math.  It should be 3!=6, not 3*3*3=27 in this case.

Comment: @jkschneider: That would be the case if John couldn't win two games in a row - but surely he can?

Comment: Maybe I should have actually read the whole question first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
void permute(String[] items, String[] soFar, int depth) {
    if (depth == soFar.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(soFar));
        return;
    }
    for(String item: items) {
        soFar[depth] = item;
            permute(items,soFar,depth+1);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
permute(new String[] {"J","T","R"},new String[3],0);
```

The first argument is an array of the items you want to permute, the second argument is an empty array that's as long as you want the permutations to be, and the third argument should be 0 to kick it off.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the pseudo-code for such a procedure:

```
proc rps()
    for outcome1 in {J,T,R}
        for outcome2 in {J,T,R}
            for outcome3 in {J,T,R}
                print (outcome1, outcome2, outcome3)
```

In an actual programming language, you could represent the set {J,T,R} as the numbers 1, 2, 3 (for example).

Of course, this snippet would only work if you knew the number of rounds before-hand. For a variable number of rounds, you would use recursion.